# Insert into sql table with one Select and one Value

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  SELECT ID from Inventory2 where Code='1' , 'Default'", con);        
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get error Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: where are u passing value for group

Comment: check your SQL external to your program, ensure it does what you think it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query should be written as

```
string cmdText = @"insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  
                    SELECT ID, 'Default' 
                    from Inventory2 
                    where Code='1'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);        
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course the ID field should not be an IDENTITY column otherwise you don't supply any value for it and let the db engine calculate its own value OR, if you really need to add your own value to that column, you enable the

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON Inventory2
```

and after the insert, stop it with OFF

If you need to insert from two tables the same number of columns you could write this

```
string cmdText =@"insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  
                 SELECT ID, 'Default' FROM Inventory2 WHERE Code='1'
                 UNION
                 SELECT ID, Category FROM INVENTORY3 WHERE Code='3'";
```

Or, if the number of fields is different you can follow this other approach

```
string cmdText =@"insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  
                 SELECT ID, 'Default' FROM Inventory2 WHERE Code='1';
                 insert into Inventory (ID,Group, Category)  
                 SELECT ID, Group, Category FROM INVENTORY3 WHERE Code='3'";
```

Comment: What if i want to use two selects and one value? insert into Inventory (ID,Group,Category)  
                    SELECT ID, 'Default' 
                    from Inventory2 
                    where Code='1' , select category for inventory3 where code=3'"

Comment: SqlServer supports batch statements. This means that you can put two sql command text together and separate them with a semicolon. The ExecuteNonQuery will execute both inserts.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You should write as :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  SELECT ID, 'Default' from Inventory2 where Code='1' ", con);        
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should select two value in  select this way

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  
SELECT ID, 'Default' from Inventory2 where Code='1' ", con);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try changing this to as follows..

```
    "insert into Inventory (ID,Group)  SELECT ID,'Default' from Inventory2 where Code='1'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an n in con, it needs to be conn